# Third party IPC calls to Chromium to capture/filter traffic

Tags: windows, winapi, google-chrome, chromium

I want to implement a network level AdBlock/NoScript-like tool for Chromium, but Chromium Extension API can not do much about controlling raw request data.

So here is the idea:

1. Capture all HTTP queries, and cancel one if URL or MIME matches.
2. Hand craft packets, like insert a header to an HTTP query.

Can this be implemented by running a thirdparty client making [IPC calls](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication) to Chromium? A snippet of sample code would be awesome!

(Note: Security is not a problem at the moment coz I only want to try it out for personal interest, not for public distribution. So it may break the sandbox mechanism.)

Answer (score 2):

No it cannot.  The Chromium network stack does not support this level of control, neither by Chromium extension, nor by IPC.  It's a work in progress.  You should watch http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50943.