# Getting Information from Google Chrome's Developer Tools

Tags: java, javascript, python, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a project that wants me to get information from Google Chrome's Developer tools. More specifically, when I open up the developer tools on my target website, under the resources tab a folder is being populated called other.

This folder is populating a list of URLs. I am curious if it is possible to somehow access or get the URLs that are being populated via any coding language (preferably python,/javascript/ajax/java).

Any input, advice, suggestions as to how to go about accessing the data within Google Chrome's developer tools would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does webkit/chrome's WebInspector Resources Inspection work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381481/how-does-webkit-chromes-webinspector-resources-inspection-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chrome Developer Tools has two parts frontend and backend and there is an API which specifies the protocol between these parts. You can see [the specification here](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/remote-debugging.html). You can use it for writing your own app instead of standard DevTools frontend.

Also there is [experimental debugging API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.debugger.html) for chrome extensions.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help. (I attempted to "vote you up" but I don't have 15 reputation yet so I am unable to).

Answer (score 0):

I have an existing [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ekpmolndgndbkmodcokbggjdfnmbajfb) which needed interaction with desktop resources. I used a `websocket` to achieve this. Maybe you could leverage this concept to access files are you required?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will have to put some thought into this suggestion. I am hoping there is a more direct way to go about this but I doubt it. ( The only dumb question is the one that is never asked).